# Remove extra margin after last child element inside of flex parent

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple parent div with `display:flex` and `flex-wrap:wrap` with children having `flex:1`. Each child has an image with a fixed width of 140px. The parent I want to have a width of 650px.

The problem: after the last element in the first row, there is some margin before the edge of the parent. How can I have the last child in each row be right up against the edge of the parent, such that the margins in between each child element in each row are equal.

```css
.parent { display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; background-color:lightblue; width: 650px; }
.child { flex: 1; }
img { float:left; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=1" /></a>
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=2" /></a>
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=3" /></a>
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=4" /></a>
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=5" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting `justify-content: space-between;` and removing the `flex:1` on the children?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 650px;
}

img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=1" /></a>
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=2" /></a>
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=3" /></a>
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=4" /></a>
  <a class="child" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140&text=5" /></a>
</div>
```